# Securely Keeping User/Pass and Using them for API calls

Tags: angularjs

I'm building an Angular app that interacts with an API secured by Basic Auth over SSL. I want users on the angular app to be able to log in with their user/pass. I want to store this user/pass across pages in the web app and use those credentials any time I want to access an API endpoint using an Angular service. Does this make sense? What's a good approach for achieving this? Should I leverage sessions? Very new to Angular here, usually I'm on the backend side of things.

Comment: If you're going for security, I wouldn't save the user/pass on the front end. There would be no security with that whatsoever. Have you thought about some sort of token based authentication instead?

Comment: You would never store the pass on the client. Passing in plain text is fine since I assume you have all the security on the backend. If you need to pull the current users credentials, make a request to the server and get it there (although you shouldn't have access to a users plain text pass)

Comment: You should definitely look into JSON Web tokens. Keeping a password in plain text anywhere in your application is a bad idea.

Comment: This won't be a publicly facing app using user/pass auth. Eventually the API will be token based, but for now I need to authenticate using the username and password. But the same principal should apply for an auth token, so what would be the optimal Angular JS way to store a token I retrieved from an API endpoint that I passed a user/password to.